# Area & Arc Length of $r=1+6\sin(\theta)+\cos(6\theta)$

Tags: calculus, maple

How do I approach this problem?

Graph the following polar curve and show that it cuts out 5 different regions. Find the area of each of those regions.

$$r=1+6\sin(\theta)+\cos(6\theta)$$

Also, find the arc length (numeric value) for each of the loops of this (the unfolded) graph.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @ncmathsadist i figured out points where $r=0$ but how do i find the area of 5 different regions?

Comment: have you plotted a graph?

Comment: @ncmathsadist yes i have

Comment: @jeffq: Have you got the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at which curve is outside and which is inside in each sector. Remember that area in polar coordinates is given by $1/2\int r^2 \, d\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graph for theta in $[0,2\pi].$

[image]